# Uploading files in a python WSGI app using AJAX and JQuery

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, file-upload, wsgi

I am trying to create a WSGI app with python3 and JQuery.  I am almost there, but I can’t seem to figure out how to upload a file (.txt) with an AJAX request.  This is as far as I’ve gotten, having consumed as much reading on the topic as I could locate.  My project directory looks like:

```
/chimera_quest
    view.py
    model.py
/static
    main.css
    main.js
/tmp
/templates
    main.html
WSGI_app.py
```

I have a form in my HTML with two radio buttons and a file upload.

```
<h3>Select an input file-type</h3>
<form id="user_input" name="user_input" method="post">

<li class="button"><input name="input_type" type="radio" value="coord" checked>Tab-delimited coordinate file</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="input_type" type="radio" value="fcatcher">Fusion Catcher</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="input_type" type="radio" value="tophat">Tophat</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="input_type" type="radio" value="tophat-post">Tophat-post</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="input_type" type="radio" value="rnastar">RNA-Star</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="input_type" type="radio" value="fcatcher">Fusion Catcher</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="input_type" type="radio" value="starfusion">Star Fusion</input></li>

<h3>Select a tissue type</h3>
<li class="button"><input name="tissue_type" type="radio" value="EPI">Epithelial</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="tissue_type" type="radio" value="HEM">Hematopoietic</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="tissue_type" type="radio" value="MES">Mesenchymal</input></li>
<li class="button"><input name="tissue_type" type="radio" value="AVG" checked>Other/Unknown</input></li>

<h3>Select a file to upload</h3>
<input type="file" id="input_file" name="input_file">
<input type="submit" class="submit" id="run_oncofuse" value="Run Oncofuse">
</form>
```

This is the Javascript/JQuery snip that I want to handle the AJAXy bit.

```
var fd = new FormData();
var user_input = $('#user_input').serialize();
var file_data = $('#input_file')[0].files[0];
fd.append( 'input_file', $( file_data ));

$.ajax({
  url: "../chimera_quest/view.py?" + user_input,
  data: fd,
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  processData: false,
  contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
  success: function(results, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log(fd)
      console.log(results)
      console.log(file_data)
// do stuff with results
    }
```

I rigged the model script to send results without user input for testing.  The JSON blob is transferred correctly and the site behaves accordingly.  My browser’s javascript console is correctly logging results and file_data does show information about the file I am attempting to upload.  I can not seem to find the file_data object within the FormData object (fd) in my console, but I assume that is because I don’t know where to look.

This is the part of the view.py script that should receive the user input:

```
if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST':
    try:
        Q_S = cgi.parse_qs(environ['QUERY_STRING'])
        input_type = Q_S.get('input_type', [''])[0]
        tissue_type = Q_S.get('tissue_type', [''])[0]

        post_env = environ.copy()
        post_env['QUERY_STRING'] = ''
        post = cgi.FieldStorage(
            fp=environ['wsgi.input'],
            environ=post_env,
            keep_blank_values=True
        )
        input_file = post['input_file']

    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        request_body = "0"
```

I am getting the user input from the radio buttons from the url with no problem, I just can’t seem to access the uploaded file in the POST request.  I’ve tried rewriting this as many ways as I could think of or find an example. I think the problem is either in creating the FormData object in the JavaScript or creating/accessing the FieldStorage object in the python, but I can’t seem to nail this one down.

Any ideas?